# JMETER: How do I run parallel JDBC requests in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, database, aws

I have defined the JDBC Connection configuration and have added multiple JDBC requests in JMeter.

Currently, when I trigger the requests, the requests are executed one after the other.

I would like to run all requests parallel with each other to distribute the load on my database

How can I simulate this scenario using Jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) is executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))

JMeter thread model assumes that:

- 1 User executes 1 Sampler at the given moment of time
- JMeter waits for the previous sampler to finish before starting execution of the next one

Therefore you have 2 options:

1. Either increase the number of threads (virtual users) on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level and let your test last long enough so all users would be up and running, for example below setup will instruct JMeter to start 100 virtual users which will be executing your JDBC Request samplers as fast as they can for 1 minute:

   [image]
2. If your requirement is a little bit different and your use case assumes single thread (virtual user) kicking off several JDBC requests in parallel - you will need to install a special plugin called Parallel Controller which was mainly designed to simulate [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) requests so it overcomes the aforementioned JMeter limitation of 1 thread - sampler at a time

   [image]

Comment: thank you, parallel controller is exactly what I was looking for